# How to normalize paginated data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I need to convert a data like this:

```
{peopleList: [{id:1, name: 'joe'}, {id: 2, name: 'john'}], page: 1, rowPerPage: 8}
```

to this model:

```
{entities: {'0': {id: 0, name: 'joe'}, '1': {id: 1, name: 'john'}, page: 1, rowPerPage: 8}, result: [0, 1]}
```

but when I add this schema:

```
const people = new schema.Entity('peopleList');
const normalizedData = normalize(_data, { peopleList: [people] });
```

I get this output:

```
{
      "entities": {
        "peopleList": {
          "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "joe"
          },
          "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "john"
          }
        }
      },
      "result": {
        "peopleList": [
          1,
          2
        ],
        "page": 1,
        "rowPerPage": 8
      }
    }
```

I don't know exactly how to make a proper schema that create result filed as my desire. maybe the correct way is to have it in result and this output is correct. any idea?